# how can i write a generic query with EF and C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

i want to write a query in entity framework like this:

```
T entity = (from e in myContext.typeof(T) )
```

i tried to use string concat but this dose not work for get a member from `myContext`

more code:

```
public T GetEntity<T>(Guid entityId, string connectionString)
{
    using (RContext rpContext = new RContext(connectionString))
    {

        var entity = (from e in rpContext.Set<T>()
                                    where e.Id == entityId
                                    select e).FirstOrDefault();
                    return (T) Convert.ChangeType(entity, typeof(T));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the generic `Set` method like this:

```
var entities = (from e in myContext.Set<T>());
```

**Update:**
You will need to add generic type constraints to your method, to ensure the generic type `T` will match the constraints already applied to the method `DbContext.Set<T>`.

**Update 2:**
You don't need to cast your entity; it is already `typeof(T)`.

```
public T GetEntity<T>(Guid entityId, string connectionString)
    where T : class
{
    using (RContext rpContext = new RContext(connectionString))
    {

        return (from e in rpContext.Set<T>()
                where e.Id == entityId
                select e).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

**Update 3:**
You can pass your predicate straight into the `FirstOrDefault` method, assuming you're not attached to the linq syntax.

```
public T GetEntity<T>(Guid entityId, string connectionString)
    where T : class
{
    using (RContext rpContext = new RContext(connectionString))
    {
        return rpContext.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == entityId);
    }
}
```

**Update 4:**
As you're using the `Id` property inside your method, you will also need to constrain your method to types which have that property - either by constraining a common interface, or a common base class. If it's a base class, you can remove the `class` constraint.

Comment: What type is `myContext`?

Comment: myContext is my DbContext

Comment: In what way does it not work? Compile error? Runtime exception?

Comment: the type T must be a refrence type in order to use it as a parametr 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Set<TEntity>()'

Comment: That's true. It must also be one of the entities that your `DbContext` serves. What are you trying to use as T?

Comment: T should be one of my entities. i have a function and many entities. i want to write a query for all of my entities in one function. i can write it with switch and if-else but i just trying generic, i think its better

Comment: Can you post some more of your code, including the part where you tried my suggestion?

Comment: sure, please check my post

Comment: can u give me a sample?

Comment: See my edit. As you're not defining `T` yet, you need to ensure that the constrainst that `DbContext.Set<T>` applies to T are also applied by whoever calls your method.

Comment: oh, god i forgat the condition tnx bro