# Entity Framework query table with different name

Tags: entity-framework, ef-model-first

I have a few tables which are exactly the same (except the table name). The data are different, and due to some specific reason, they **cannot be merged into one single table**.

Example:

```
TableA (
    Value1 INT NULL,
    Value2 INT NULL
)

TableB (
    Value1 INT NULL,
    Value2 INT NULL
)

.... etc ....
```

I need to perform same complex calculations / operations to all the tables (which are exactly the same). How can I do that with EF?

In traditional SQL query, we can construct query string by altering the **FROM <*table name*>**. But I can't figure how I can do that with EF

Note: EF model-first approach

Thanks in advance

Comment: added an answer

Answer (score 0):

This question might be a possible duplicate
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697161/how-can-i-write-a-generic-query-with-ef-and-c-sharp) is the link,

You can use above post to get the list of entities you want.

Try this query when you have the list of entities you want

```
      foreach (var table in entities)
        {
          var record =  (from x in table 
                where x.Value1 == 1
                select new CommonTableModel()
                {
                          Value1  = x.Value1 , 
                          Value2  = x.Value2 
                }).ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Inherit both classes(`Employer`, `Customer`) from common parent class - `Person`.
2. All common methods should become generic with constraint - `where T : Person`, this way you will have access to all properties of both classes inside these methods.

**Implementation:**

```
public abstract class Person
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
}

public class Employer : Person
{}

public class Customer : Person
{}

public List<T> GetPersonsOlderThan20Years<T>() where T : Person, new()
{
    //any common logic
    return context.Set<T>().Where(x => x.Age > 20).ToList();
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var employers = GetPersonsOlderThan20Years<Employer>();
var customers = GetPersonsOlderThan20Years<Customer>();
```

Answer (score 0):

create a generic entity

for specific row in an entity

```
//int id or whatever your [key] attribute is
public T GetSelected<T>(int id) where T : class
{
    return _dbContext.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
}

var selectedFromEntity1 = GetSelected<Entity1>(idOfEntity1);
var selectedFromEntity2 = GetSelected<Entity2>(idOfEntity2);
```

for all the rows of an entity

```
public List<T> GetAll<T>() where T : class
{
    return _dbContext.Set<T>().ToList();
}

var dataFromEntity1 = GetAll<Entity1>();
var dataFromEntity2 = GetAll<Entity2>();
```

or if you want to add paging or conditions

```
public IQueryable<T> GetAll<T>()
{
   return _dbContext.Set<T>().AsQueryable();
}


var dataFromEntity1 = GetAll<Entity1>();
var resultFrom1 = dataFromEntity1
                     .Where(x => x.Property1 == "searchFilter") //user input searchFilter
                     .Skip(pageSize* pageNumber) //user input page size and page number
                     .Take(pageSize) //user input page size
                 .ToList();

var dataFromEntity2 = GetAll<Entity2>();
var resultFrom2 = dataFromEntity2
                     .Where(x => x.Property1 == "searchFilter") //user input searchFilter
                     .Skip((pageSize * pageNumber)-pageSize) //user input page size and page number
                     .Take(pageSize) //user input page size
                 .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think raw queries are your anser: [Raw SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql)

So you can basically:

```
   using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
   {
      var blogs = context.Blogs.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.Blogs").ToList(); 
   }
```

And exchange the name of the table as you suggested.

Note: I have not tried this, and for sure the tables must be completely identical (even column ordering)